# How can I monitor the bandwidth usage of all devices on my local network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, network-monitoring

I have a router which doesn't show what speeds each wifi device uses from the WAN.

Is there a program or tool which tells me the current upload/download speed on the network of any connected devices?

I'm using Windows 8.

Comment: Some details on the hardware you currently have would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cfos-speed to replace the original network drivers. You can install it on each pc in the local network and configure it to monitor the full traffic. It's a tool to optimize ping and  bandwidth and  it can also shape the traffic.
I found this in a readme file:

> cFosSpeed can now communicate with other cFosSpeed drivers on your
>   LAN to   share statistical data of how much each of them sent.  This
>   increases the   accuracy of traffic shaping with more than one
>   machine.  We call this   feature "net_talk".  Statistics are sent out
>   as UDP packets (by default on   port 889) five times a second with TTL
>   1 to your local subnet broadcast   address, so they will never leave
>   your LAN.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to flash your router with a more clever firmware.

For example, I own the ancient Linksys WRT54G, which can be flashed with almost any OpenWRT-based custom firmware. There are thousands of packages available for this project, including network monitoring tools that can supply you with bandwidth statistics.

This is not a very generic answer to your question, since I don't have information on your router, but it might still be helpful and cheap solution.